# Finding conjugacy classes of $PGL_{2}(\mathbb{F}_{q})$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, matrices

Assume $q$ is odd. How does one go about finding the conjugacy classes of $PGL_{2}(\mathbb{F}_{q})$? I know that for $GL_{2}(\mathbb{F}_{q})$, one can consider the possible Jordan Normal Forms of the matrices and with some luck, choose representatives whose conjugacy class is large enough such that when I sum all the conjugacy class sizes I get the whole group.

Comment: $PGL(2,q)$ is just $GL(2,q)$ quotient the center.  Thus conjugacy classes in $PGL(2,q)$ are just the equivalence classes of elements in $GL(2,q)$ given by the following relation: $g\equiv h$ if $g=h^kz$, where $g,h,k\in GL(2,q)$ and $z$ is central.  Now central elements are multiples of the identity, so all you're doing is taking a normal conjugacy class in $GL(2,q)$, and maybe doing some scalar multiplication. In particular, Jordan normal  forms mostly solve the problem.

Comment: What do you mean by $h^{k}$ in $g = h^{k}z$?

Comment: The conjugate of $h$ by $k$, $h^k=k^{-1}hk$.