# Conjugacy classes in PGL(2,n)

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, representation-theory

I'm working on a project that requires me to write out some character tables, and I know part of my computation is wrong for $PGL(2,n)$, would appreciate some input.

So, restricting down from conjugacy classes in $GL(2,n)$ and using the the orbit stabilizer theorem to count elements, I came up with the following:

Our classes are (listed by coset representatives): $$\begin{bmatrix}
1 &0 \\ 
 0& 1
\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}
1 &r \\ 
 0&1 
\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}
1 & r^2\\ 
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}
 r^2&0 \\ 
 0& 1
\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}
 r&0 \\ 
 0& 1
\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}
x &\epsilon \\ 
 1& x
\end{bmatrix}$$ where $x\in\mathbb{F}_n$, $r$ ranges over all of the quadratic nonresidues and $\epsilon$ is a fixed quadratic nonresidue.

There are, respectively $$1,\frac{n-1}{2}, \frac{n-1}{2}, \frac{n-3}{2}, n-2,n$$ distinct classes following from our choices of $x,r$.

The orbit-stabilizer theorem applied to the conjugation map tells us that $|Conj(a)||C_{PGL(2,\mathbb{F}_n)}(a)|=|PGL(2,\mathbb{F}_n)|$. Therefore we compute the centralizers:

$$|C_{PGL(2,\mathbb{F}_n)}(I)|=|PGL(2,\mathbb{F}_n)|$$

$$|C_{PGL(2,\mathbb{F}_n)}(\begin{bmatrix}
1 &r \\ 
 0&1 
\end{bmatrix})|=n(n-1)$$

$$|C_{PGL(2,\mathbb{F}_n)}(\begin{bmatrix}
1 & r^2\\ 
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix})|=n(n-1)$$

$$|C_{PGL(2,\mathbb{F}_n)}(\begin{bmatrix}
 r^2&0 \\ 
 0& 1
\end{bmatrix})|=(n-1)(n-2)$$

$$|C_{PGL(2,\mathbb{F}_n)}(\begin{bmatrix}
 r&0 \\ 
 0& 1
\end{bmatrix})|=(n-1)(n-2)$$

$$|C_{PGL(2,\mathbb{F}_n)}(\begin{bmatrix}
x &\epsilon \\ 
 1& x
\end{bmatrix})|=n(n-1)$$

These are obtained by direct computation, take an arbitrary matrix $g\in PGL(2,n)$, multiply it on both sides, this creates a system of equations relating the entries in the matrices, count the matrices satisfying these conditions. Easier than it sounds.

Since $|PGL(2,n)|=n^3-n$ we get that the size of the conjugacy classes are, respectively, $$1,n+1,n+1,\frac{n(n+1)}{n-2},\frac{n(n+1)}{n-2},n+1$$

Therefore by the class equation we should have that the sum of the order of all these classes is $n^3-n$. But there's my problem, since $$1+(n+1)\frac{n-1}{2}2+\frac{n(n+1)}{n-2}[\frac{n-3}{2}+n-2]+n(n+1)=(3 n^3)/(2 (n-2))-(2 n^2)/(n-2)+2 n^2-(7 n)/(2 (n-2))+n$$ which is very far off.

So, where'd I screw up?

Answer (score 1):

It will be useful to start with $GL_2(\Bbb F_p)$ first, and then pass to $PGL_2(\Bbb F_p)$, using the remarks given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115246/finding-conjugacy-classes-of-pgl-2-mathbbf-q).
Actually every matrix of $GL_2(\Bbb F_p)$ is conjugate to a matrix of one of the following forms:
$$\begin{bmatrix}a&0\\0&a\end{bmatrix}\quad\begin{bmatrix}a&1\\0&a\end{bmatrix}\quad\begin{bmatrix}a&0\\0&b\end{bmatrix}\quad\begin{bmatrix}d&c\\1&d\end{bmatrix}$$

where $a\neq 0$, $b\neq 0$, $a\neq b$, and $c$ is a quadratic nonresidue mod $p$. Counting these kind of matrices (without double-counting the matrices of the third form above), we see that $GL_2(\Bbb F_p)$ has $(p-1)(p+1)$ conjugacy classes.

- For central matrices, their conjugacy classes each have size $1$.
- For matrices of the second form, their conjugacy classes have size $(p-1)(p+1)$
- For matrices of the third form, their conjugacy classes have size $p(p+1)$
- And for the fourth form, their conjugacy classes have size $p(p-1)/2$

Comment: There's a slightly larger conjugacy class for your last type of matrix if we consider $GL(2,\mathbb{F}_q),q=p^k$, but yeah, those are the matrices I started with. I'll look into using Jordan normal forms cause I'm guessing most of the error here is coming from overlapping conjugacy classes. (And a couple computational errors I preened since I've been editing it, but still not quite getting there.)

Comment: Hm, okay. So the first three matrices are in normal form in $GL$ as is; considered under $PGL$, all of the first type (scalar matrices) are equivalent to the identity, all of the second type are equivalent to $\begin{bmatrix}1&x\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$ (consider multiplying by $x^{-1}$ and changing variable), and the third type are equivalent to $\begin{bmatrix}x&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$ if $y\neq x^{-1}$ and to $\begin{bmatrix}x^2&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$ otherwise, a split class. (con't)

Comment: The last group of matrices has Jordan form outside the group (specifically it has eigenvalues in the field extension $\mathbb{F}_{n^2}$). So we obtain pretty much the same information I have up (there's an error in the above splitting the classes $\begin{bmatrix}1&x\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$, $\begin{bmatrix}1&x^2\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$ that's unnecessary, and my presentation overall is sloppy).

Comment: I think it's not the classes so much as the combinatorics. This group is being finicky on me.